# Group base permission rest api in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am using Django rest framework for my login api. Now i want to login only certain group user through api. I have created group and assigned user to the group.I have created a permission class and used to APIView but it's show ""Authentication credentials were not provided."

Here is my permissions.py class

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class FanOnlyPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and request.user.groups.filter(name='fan'):
            return True
        return False
```

Here is my view.py

```
from rest_framework import views, permissions, status, generics
class UserLoginApiView(generics.GenericAPIView):
"""
User Login Api View
"""
permission_classes = (FanOnlyPermission, )

def post(self, request):
    """
    Handle POST request
    :param request:
    :return:
    """

    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have tried through postman. when i print request.user from permission.py it shoed "Anonymous user".

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using ? Have you set the rest authentication variables in settings file ?

Comment: Here is my setting.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
actually i want to authentication where login api check only group. if user exist the group then login other wise will be showed permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom authentication backend,
See this answer: [how to create login authentication based on some condition in django restframework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853729/11100417)

And then config the  `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in the settings.py:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['accounts.backends.AuthBackend']
```