# how to create login authentication based on some condition in django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Hi Everyone current I am using default token base authentication, but now I need to some restriction on login time, I have a model called as **Team** where I assign a team name to multiple managers(users)
I need to login only those users  have team. also login based on username, password and get output token and team name, please help me out.

**models.py**

```py
class Team(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=team_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='City')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Maybe you could create a middleware which bypasses the login on certain conditions. You can bypass the login by setting the `_cached_user` attribute on the request. In this case, make sure you place your custom middleware before Django auth middleware. For creating your own custom middleware see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/. Another option is to completely override the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` and replace it with your own.

Comment: @vinkomlacic i am simple creating login api for generating token but i have one condition while login customer first check username exist in Team table or if exist then login otherwise not after login i want also team name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom authentication backend:

[Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

in the `authenticate` method of your custom `AuthBackend` you must return only those users which have team. sample code:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

User = get_user_model()


class AuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Authenticates against settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    """

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            User().set_password(password)
        else:
            user_is_active = self.user_can_authenticate(user)
            user_has_team = user.team_set.all().count() > 0  # Check this line
            if user.check_password(password) and user_is_active and user_has_team:
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

Comment: yes i know but need login only those users  which have team, currently all user login and generating token via (path('login',obtain_auth_token,name="login"),) auth.

Comment: @KarishmaUpadhyay I added sample code. check the line `if user.check_password(password) and user_is_active and user_has_team:` and the line before it